# How do I split a string on a fixed character sequence?

Tags: java, string, split

Suppose I have following string:

```
String asd = "this is test ass this is test"
```

and I want to split the string using "ass" character sequence.

I used:

```
asd.split("ass");
```

It doesn't work. What do I need to do?

Comment: i would have used `"this is test foo this is test"` as an example though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Splitter {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String asd = "this is test ass this is test";
        final String[] parts = asd.split("ass");
        for (final String part : parts) {
            System.out.println(part);
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
this is test 
 this is test
```

Under Java 6. What output were you expecting?

Answer (score 9):

It seems to work fine for me:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String asd = "this is test ass this is test";
        String[] bits = asd.split("ass");
        for (String bit : bits) {
            System.out.println("'" + bit + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
'this is test '
' this is test'
```

Is your real delimiter different perhaps? Don't forget that split uses its parameter as a regular expression...

Answer (score 1):

```
String asd = "this is test foo this is test";
String[] parts = asd.split("foo");
```

Try this it will work